# Linking on Two Fields with 0s Trimmed - Access

Tags: ms-access

I have two separate queries which trim the 0s from two separate tables using the following functions

```
Replace(LTrim(Replace(Nz([03_Account_Matrix].[PORT_ACCT_DDA]),"0"," "))," ","0")
```

The Nz is because there are some nulls in the first table.

```
Replace(LTrim(Replace(Nz([04_Balance].[Account]),"0"," "))," ","0")
```

The reason for this is because they might be the same account, but have a different number of leading 0s (Terrible design, I know).

```
An example number is 00040007613 and 0040007613 which are the same and get trimmed to be so.
```

However, when I linked the trimmed queries on this account number, there are no results; although, in the queries, they are the same value. Why is this occurring? My best guess is because the strings might contain a different number of spaces....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, different number of spaces is same issue as different number of zeros. Why are you replacing with spaces? Why not just empty string?

Based on the example provided:

`Replace("00040007613","0","") = Replace("0040007613","0","")`

However consider:

`Format("00040007613","00000000000") = Format("0040007613","00000000000")`

Comment: Thanks, I used the Format style you suggested and it cleared the problem right up!

Comment: wouldn't Replace("00040007613","0","")  result in 47613?

Comment: Yes it would. And based on the example provided the two values would be equivalent. However, that is not much of an example set to base analysis on. And probably don't want to remove the middle zeros because I expect you do have some values like 00000047613 and 00000407613, etc. and therefore the results likely erroneous, which is why I offered the Format option. Will 11 places always be enough?

Comment: Just occurred to me the Val() function might also serve this situation.